# why the Last value of LAG function does not yield any value?

Tags: sql, lag

From my understanding, I can use LAG() function to access the value of previous row. I am creating new columns 'survived' and 'disenrolled' based on the value of status from previous row. Month '2022-11' has status 1. Since it's not NULL I would expect the survived value for row with month '2022-12' to be 1 and disnerolled to be 0. But the results table have those values as NAs. What is happening here? Why are those values not showing?

`select * from tmp_enrollment_long_2;`

| person_id | month | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-12 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-01 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-02 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-03 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-04 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-05 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-06 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-07 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-08 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-09 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-10 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-11 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2022-12 | 1 |

```
SELECT * 
,CAST( lag( status IS NOT NULL, 1 ) OVER( partition BY person_id ORDER BY month DESC ) AS SMALLINT ) AS survived
,CAST( lag( status IS     NULL, 1 ) OVER( partition BY person_id ORDER BY month DESC ) AS SMALLINT ) AS disenrolled
FROM tmp_enrollment_long_2;
```

| person_id | month | status | survived | disenrolled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-12 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-01 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-02 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-03 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-04 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-05 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-06 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-07 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-08 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-09 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-10 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-11 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2022-12 | 1 |  |  |

Comment: @phili_b See the example here - https://www.codecademy.com/resources/docs/sql/window-functions/lag
I am doing something similar

Comment: I've never seen condition in `LAG()` like that. Which SQL is it ? In normal SQL you cannot write this. Try to use `Case when status IS NOT NULL then blabla else other blabla2 End` in the `LAG()`. (Writen after because was deleted)

Comment: I know this. The part that is strange for me is `status IS NOT NULL` in the `LAG()` without `case when`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"value of status from previous row" using window of "ORDER BY month DESC" actually means "value from next month". In your data 2022-12 is last month, available, there is no next month - therefore the values are null.

If you need a non-null value you can use `coalesce` function to get some reasonable default:

```
coalesce(lag( status IS NOT NULL, 1 ), 1)
```